# Eclipse plug-in for launching several run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin

I want to create plug-in which allow to run several chosen(ctrl+click) configuration from “Run Configurations” form by one click. I have made plug-in for contextual menu(extension point org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus),but I can't find “objectClass” for configuration.

What name of the class object of a configuration(conf could have different types – JUnit, Eclipse appl and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing, just download and use the plugin from sources attached to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=39900#c30 ("A plug-in project to show a basic workflow" zip file)

Cheers,
Max